# How Can I Define Link Colours for a Div?

Tags: css, html, colors, hyperlink

I'm trying to change the properties for the links in only one specific dev layer. Ideally I'd be able to have a code which kept every single link in the document the same colour despite it's status, but I don't think that's possible.

This is the coding that I have at the moment, but it's not working:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color:#B7B7B7;
background-image:url('http://pophatesfags.site90.net/pophatesfags.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
}

.text {
font-style: italic;
border-bottom:1px dashed black;
}

div.home {
a:link { color: #70DB93; }
a:visited { color: #70DB93; }
a:hover { color: #70DB93; }
a:active { color: #70DB93; }
}

</style>
</head>

<font color="70DB93"
<div id="home" class="div" style="position:absolute; width:715; height:42; left:27%; top:178px">
<span class="text">
<a href="http://www.pophatesfags.site90.net/home.html">home</font></a></div></style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't worry Gareth, it's meant to be ironic!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I assume you want to change the color of the link in 'home' div.
The CSS code will be -

```
#home a:link { color: #70DB93; }
#home a:visited { color: #70DB93; }
#home a:hover { color: #70DB93; }
#home a:active { color: #70DB93; }
```

Try it and let us know!

Comment: Ahhh that worked perfectly, thank you so much! :) How did I miss that?

Comment: Good to know that! You may like to accept the answer so that other knows its working!

Comment: Awesome! I did not even think this was possible. In fact a few years back I saw a similar question answered with "its not possible". BUt it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color:#B7B7B7;
background-image:url('http://pophatesfags.site90.net/pophatesfags.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
}

.text {
font-style: italic;
border-bottom:1px dashed black;
}

div#home a:link { color: #70DB93; }
div#home a:visited { color: #70DB93; }
div#home a:hover { color: #70DB93; }
div#home a:active { color: #70DB93; }

</style>
</head>

<div id="home" class="div" style="position:absolute; width:715; height:42; left:27%; top:178px">
<span class="text">
<a href="http://www.pophatesfags.site90.net/home.html">home</a></div>
```

​

http://jsbin.com/ujivoy/1/edit